# Filter by key in 2d or multidimensional array using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am tyring to filter by a particualar key in my array that is nested inside a multi arrary. I keep getting returned my filter is not a function. I am trying to return only the array that has the object key "assets"

My Data Array:

```
    const variableOpts = [
       [
          {
             "assets":"EP009285440323",
             "rootId":"21253358",
          },
          {
             "assets":"EP009285440323",
             "rootId":"21253358",
          },
          {
             "assets":"EP009285440323",
             "rootId":"21253358",
          }
       ],
       [
          {
             "TMSId":"EP035579760050",
             "rootId":"21253391",
          },
          {
             "TMSId":"EP035579760050",
             "rootId":"21253391",
          },
          {
             "TMSId":"EP035579760050",
             "rootId":"21253391",
          }
       ],
       [
          {
             "TMSId":"EP033168400060",
             "rootId":"21166708",
          },
          {
             "TMSId":"EP033168400060",
             "rootId":"21166708",
          },
          {
             "TMSId":"EP033168400060",
             "rootId":"21166708",
          }
       ],
[
          {
             "assets":"EP00928544",
             "rootId":"111",
          },
          {
             "assets":"EP00",
             "rootId":"222",
          },
          {
             "assets":"EP00928544]",
             "rootId":"444",
          }
       ],
    ]
```

JS:

```
const filResults = variableOpts.map((el) => {
      return el.map((prg) => prg.filter((obj) => obj.includes("assets")));
    });
    console.log("filData", filResults); <---Uncaught TypeError: prg.filter is not a function"
```

Desired Output:

```
    [
          {
             "assets":"EP009285440323",
             "rootId":"21253358",
          },
          {
             "assets":"EP009285440323",
             "rootId":"21253358",
          },
          {
             "assets":"EP009285440323",
             "rootId":"21253358",
          }
       ],
[
          {
             "assets":"EP00928544",
             "rootId":"111",
          },
          {
             "assets":"EP00",
             "rootId":"222",
          },
          {
             "assets":"EP00928544]",
             "rootId":"444",
          }
       ],
    ]
```

Comment: Is there a problem with `variableOpts[0][0]`? If those objects could be in any inner array, `variableOpts.flat().filter(e => e.assets)` or `variableOpts.filter(e => e.some(f => f.assets))` or `variableOpts.find(e => e.some(f => f.assets))` if you just want the first? Could also use `every` instead of `some` if all objects should have the key? Hard to tell which one you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter the array by looking into the nested arrays for the wanted property.

```js
const
    variableOpts = [[{ assets: "EP009285440323", rootId: "21253358" }, { assets: "EP009285440323", rootId: "21253358" }, { assets: "EP009285440323", rootId: "21253358" }], [{ TMSId: "EP035579760050", rootId: "21253391" }, { TMSId: "EP035579760050", rootId: "21253391" }, { TMSId: "EP035579760050", rootId: "21253391" }], [{ TMSId: "EP033168400060", rootId: "21166708"} , { TMSId: "EP033168400060", rootId: "21166708" }, { TMSId: "EP033168400060", rootId: "21166708" }], [{ assets: "EP00928544", rootId: "111" }, { assets: "EP00", rootId: "222" }, { assets: "EP00928544]", rootId: "444" }]],
    result = variableOpts.filter(a => a.length && a.some(o => 'assets' in o));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```